# Is it possible to link a cell In Excel to a local file with a querystring?

Tags: excel, excel-2003

I had wanted to put a solution onto a thumb drive or dvd to be distributed as needed.  I have a couple html pages with javascript to display photos and some other info.  I also have an excel spreadsheet (2003) that I wanted to link to the html page.  However when I try to use a querystring I get a warning from excel stating that it "cannot open the specified file."

edit: I use javascript to parse the querystring and load a specific photo and some info.

This does not work:

```
=HYPERLINK("site_photos.htm?p=1", "photo 1")
```

This works:

```
=HYPERLINK("site_photos.htm", "photo 1")
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

edit:

Okay, I've tried using ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink procedure using the extrainfo and not using the extrainfo parameter.  This did not work.  I also tried using a shell command.  This also did not pass the querystring either.  It looks like I will need another solution.

edit:

Here's the javascript function used to retrieve the querystring.  The querystring is not in the window.location.href so this will not work when called.

```
function parseUrl(name)
{
      name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
      var regexStr = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
      var regex = new RegExp( regexStr );
      var results = regex.exec(window.location.href); 
      if( results == null )
        return "";
      else
        return results[1];
}
```

Comment: Who is interpreting your "?p=1" ?

Comment: You sure you want a query-string here and not an anchor?  "site_photos.html#photo1"?  As @belisarius points out a query-string is usually consumed by a server-side program (CGI, etc...).  Unless you are running a server locally, I don't see how that's going to work.

Comment: @Mark Tnx for clarifying. I guess something like that is going on. I answered and then deleted my answer until the running environment is clear.

Comment: Javascript will consume the parameters passed by the querystring.  I have thousands of photos here and did not want to make thousands of static html files.  This will not be on a server, but on a distributable DVD.

Comment: @belisarius I added the JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it is possible to perform the original task or not, I have opted for a different solution.  I will use image controls to view the photos and other controls for navigation.